# How to test accuracy of a trained knn model in R Studio?

Tags: r

The objective is to train a model to predict the default variable. Train a KNN model with k = 13 using the knn3() function and calculate the test accuracy.

My code to solve this problem so far is:

```
# load packages
library("mlbench")
library("tibble")
library("caret")
library("rpart")

# set seed 
set.seed(49607)

# load data and coerce to tibble
default = as_tibble(ISLR::Default)

# split data
dft_trn_idx = sample(nrow(default), size = 0.8 * nrow(default))
dft_trn = default[dft_trn_idx, ]
dft_tst = default[-dft_trn_idx, ]

# check data
dft_trn

# fit knn model
mod_knn = knn3(default ~ ., data = dft_trn, k = 13)

# make "predictions" with knn model
new_obs = data.frame(balance = 421, income = 28046)
predtrn = predict(mod_knn, new_obs, type = "prob")

confusionMatrix(predtrn,dft_trn)
```

at the last line of the code chunk, I get error "Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels." I am unsure as to how I can fix this, or if this is even the correct method to measure the test accuracy.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: your new `new_obs` is missing two of the features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as machine learner you are doing well because a necessary step is to split data into train and test set. The issue I found is that you are trying to compare a new prediction from data outside from test and train test. The principle in ML is to train the model on train dataset and then make predictions on test dataset in order to finally evaluate performance. You have the datasets for that (`dft_tst`). Here the code to obtain confusion matrix. As a reminder, if you have one predicted label without having the real label to compare, the confusion matrix will not be computed. Here the code to obtain the desired matrix:

```
# load packages
library("mlbench")
library("tibble")
library("caret")
library("rpart")

# set seed 
set.seed(49607)

# load data and coerce to tibble
default = as_tibble(ISLR::Default)
```

Now, we split into train and test sets:

```
# split data
dft_trn_idx = sample(nrow(default), size = 0.8 * nrow(default))
dft_trn = default[dft_trn_idx, ]
dft_tst = default[-dft_trn_idx, ]
```

We train the model:

```
# fit knn model
mod_knn = knn3(default ~ ., data = dft_trn, k = 13)
```

Now, the key part is making predictions on test set (or any labelled set) and obtain the confusion matrix:

```
# make "predictions" with knn model
predtrn = predict(mod_knn, dft_tst, type = "class")
```

In order to compute the confusion matrix, the predictions and original labels must have the same lenght:

```
#Confusion matrix
confusionMatrix(predtrn,dft_tst$default)
```

Output:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   No  Yes
       No  1929   67
       Yes    1    3
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.966           
                 95% CI : (0.9571, 0.9735)
    No Information Rate : 0.965           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.4348          
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.0776          
                                          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 3.211e-15       
                                          
            Sensitivity : 0.99948         
            Specificity : 0.04286         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.96643         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.75000         
             Prevalence : 0.96500         
         Detection Rate : 0.96450         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.99800         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.52117         
                                          
       'Positive' Class : No
```